# How do I know what entity to remove base on CKQueryNotification?

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

I have two record types in Cloudkit: **Service** and **Goal** and it corresponds to Entities: `Service` and `Goal` in coredata model. I can create, update, or delete them. The question is about deletion.

I fetch pending notifications using CloudKit. I can determine what kind of operation it is base on `queryNotificationReason` property. If it is deletion there is no way to determine what kind of property should I remove from my core data database with related ID.

Any way how to do this? So far I did it like this for recordID I get from `CKQueryNotification`:

```
class func delete(with recordID: CKRecordID) {

    MagicalRecord.save({ context in

        if let service = Service.find(withIdentifier: recordID.recordName, in: context) {

            service.mr_deleteEntity(in: context)

        } else if let goal = Goal.find(withIdentifier: recordID.recordName, in: context) {

            goal.mr_deleteEntity(in: context)
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: You need to clarify your question. It is vague.

Comment: I did update the question...

Answer (score 1):

A query notification for a deletion only gives you a `CKRecordID`. This means the record id must include all of the information you need to know to process a deletion.

I solve this problem by creating record IDs that include the record type and a key. Then when needed, I can split the record ID's recordName into the entity name and key and use those values as needed.